# Using npaths in the forecast function in R vs arima.sim() function

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, bootstrap, simulation

I have data for 100 days which I've already fit using an ARIMA(0,1,1) and I'm looking to forecast my potential returns for the next 5 days. Furthermore, I'm assuming the returns are independent and normally distributed. I'm particularly interested in obtaining the different potential returns at time T = 105 under different scenarios to see whether this value is higher or lower than my guess. Does anyone know how to simulate and obtain a path of returns in R so that I have let say N different potential returns at time T = 105? I tried using forecast() with my ARIMA model and npaths = 5 using bootstrap however I'm not able to get the different scenarios and I'm not sure if arima.sim() will help. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Use the simulate() function applied to your ARIMA model object.

Comment: Hi @RobHyndman thanks for responding. I had a followup question. Let's say my arima model is saved as model1. How would I then use the simulate function to obtain different potential returns at time T=105, say N different potential returns? It seems like the simulate() function only returns a number of simulations rather than a simulation for the potential return at time T =105 which is what I'm looking for. Thank you once again.

Comment: If you have a new question, please open a new post - do not ask follow-up questions in the comments; and instead of repeated verbal thanks (in advance and afterwards), please accept the answer below - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Set up a loop like this:

```r
library(forecast)
y <- ts(fma::ibmclose[1:100])
model1 <- Arima(y, order=c(0,1,1))
N <- 50
sim <- ts(matrix(ncol=N, nrow=5), start=end(y)+1)
for(i in seq(NCOL(sim))) {
  sim[,i] <- simulate(model1, 5)
}
# Simulated values at time T=105
hist(sim[5,])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Each column of `sim` contains one simulated future sample path of the process. So each row of `sim` contains a set of random draws from the forecast distribution.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.